# Randomized algo (randomized pivot selection) gives different output everytime i run the program

Tags: c++, random, quicksort, random-seed

I am dealing with a large data set, so i decided to implement the linear selection algorithm which is derived from the quick sort algorithm, as it gives the nth smallest element from an array in almost linear time. Here is my implementation:

```
long Random(long lower, long upper)
{
    long num = (rand() % (upper - lower + 1)) + lower;
    return num;
}
long partition(long arr[], long l, long r, long pivot)
{
    long j = l;
    long pi = arr[pivot];
    swap(&arr[pivot], &arr[r]);
    for (int i = l; i < r; i++)
    {
        if ((arr[i] < pi) && (j != i))
        {
            swap(&arr[j], &arr[i]);
            j++;
        }
    }
    swap(&arr[r], &arr[j]);
    return j;
}

long select(long arr[], long l, long r, long n, int i)
{
    if (n == 1)
    {
        return arr[0];
    }
    long pivot = Random(l, r);
    long x = partition(arr, l, r, pivot);
    if (x == i)
    {
        return arr[x];
    }
    else if (x > i)
    {
        return select(arr, l, x, (x - 1), i);
    }
    else
    {
        return select(arr, x, r, (n - x), (i - x));
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(0));
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("integers.txt", "r");
    long arr[SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        fscanf(f, "%ld", &arr[i]);
    }
    fclose(f);

    long in;
    cout << "Enter the index you want to find - ";
    cin >> in;
    cout << select(arr, 0, (SIZE - 1), SIZE, (in - 1)) << endl;
}
```

Not only it gives the incorrect answer, it gives a different answer every time. I have no clue why, is there something wrong in the way i have used srand and rand functions, or is their something else wrong with my algorithm?

Thank You in advance

Comment: Is the `swap` function in your code `std::swap`? If that's the case, you should write `swap(arr[j], arr[i]);` and the likes.

Comment: @Bob__ I have implemented the swap function and it works perfectly, that's not the problem here

Comment: If you're allowed to use the standard library the [`std::nth_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) algorithm exists and does what you want.

Comment: @Blastfurnace actually, i wanted to use this algo on a class i created. I did not share that as it would've added useless complexity to my question. That's why i am working on my own version of "nth element", but there is something wrong with my algorithm here.

Comment: Consider the `partition` function. Have you tested it, passing multiple known arrays and pivot values and checking the resulting array?

Answer (score 0):

In `partition`, `arr[j]` is swapped with `arr[i]` when `arr[i] < pi`, but we don't know anything about `arr[j]`, other than `j` starts from `l` (not 1, l. Please don't use a single `l` as a variable name, it's prone to misunderstandings).

Given OP's signature and keeping almost the same algorithm, it could be written like the following.

```
long partition(long arr[], long left, long right, long pivot_index)
{
    using std::swap;
    
    // "Protect" the pivotal value moving it to the right.
    long pivot = arr[pivot_index];
    swap(arr[right], arr[pivot_index]);

    // Find the first element of the right partition.
    long j = left;
    while ( arr[j] < pivot  &&  j < right)
        ++j;
    
    // Corner case, the pivot is the max value too.
    if ( j == right)
        return j;

    // Move all the elements less than the pivotal value to the left.
    for (long i = j + 1; i < right; ++i)
    {
        if ( arr[i] < pivot )
        {
            swap(arr[j], arr[i]);
            // j is the index of the first element not less than the pivot.
            ++j;
        }
    }

    // Put the pivot "back" in place.
    swap(arr[j], arr[right]);
    return j;
}
```

---

`select` needs some adjustments too.

```
// ...
if (x == i)
{
    return arr[x];
}
else if (x > i)
{
    return select(arr, left, x - 1, x - left, i);
    //                       ^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^
    // Given that x > i, I know that x is wrong and that x > left
}
else
{
    return select(arr, x + 1, right, right - x, i);
    //                 ^^^^^         ^^^^^^^^^  ^
    // 'i' must be passed untouched, it refers to the whole array
}
```

Note that you don't really need to pass the size (number of elements) of the array/partition, it can be deduced by its extremes.

Also note that in the Standard Library is common to pass a *range* of values as a couple of iterators (or an actual [`std::range`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/range), since C++20). See e.g. [`std::nth_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/nth_element) and [`std::partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) along with their possible implementations.